# How to share a very large voice memo to Dropbox from iPod?

Tags: ios, sharing, dropbox, voice-memo

I am a college student and have recorded an interview for a speech assignment on my iPod. It is too large to email (about 24min). I have Dropbox on my iPod but when I try to "share" the voice memo, Dropbox is not an option. I don't have a computer to sync my iPod either.

What can I do to get this turned in?

Answer (score 5):

Since you only have two sharing options in Voice Memos (Email, Message), you are obviously limited to those two things (clearly excluding a computer which you don't have access to).

Caveat: the following steps worked for me, but I didn't have a super-large voice memo to test it with.

1. Turn off "Send as SMS" in Settings.app -> Messages (if enabled).
2. Open Voice Memos.app and select the memo you want to share.
3. Tap "Share", and select "Message".
4. Type in a *bogus* number.

   - This shouldn't be hard because we just limited our playing field to only iMessage users by turning off SMS alternate. The goal is to **not** reach someone obviously.
5. Hit send.
6. You should receive an error message that the message failed to send. *(Perfect.)*
7. Tap the memo, and then select the "Share" icon in the upper right corner.
8. Select "Open in DropBox".

Comment: Very nice hack. I usually push it through iMessage to the end, but your's is a better "hack". Dupe this [rdar://13741824](http://openradar.appspot.com/13741824)

Comment: Some other solutions: http://caseysousa.com/get-large-voice-recordings-off-your-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully now **Save to Dropbox** appears as an action in the share sheet.

[image: Voice Memos app Share sheet]